# DotNetNuke using PNG images with Transparency

Tags: internet-explorer-6, png, transparency, dotnetnuke

I have a DotNetNuke site where my main logo is a PNG file using transparency.  I tried GIF but the quality wasn't good enough.

Anyways it worked great on IE7 but I just saw my site in IE6 and noticed that the transparency isn't working with my logo.

Does anyone know of a quick way to fix this in a DotNetNuke portal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know that it's a DotNetNuke issue as much as it is IE6. Anyways, here's a site that shows you how to work around IE6's png issues. Hope it helps.

http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

Answer (score 3):

For a DotNetNuke-specific way to fix the issue, you can install the [DotNetNuke Widget Suite](http://dnnwidgets.com), and use the [IE PNG Fix widget](http://dnnwidgets.com/Widgets/IEPNGFix) on your site (probably include it in your skin).

That said, if you're going to need to integrate something into your skin anyway, the widget doesn't give you a whole lot of advantage.  If you're able to evaluate and integrate the techniques in the accepted answer, that's probably a better route to take.

Answer (score 2):

IE6 doesn't support transparent PNGs. It isn't a DotNetNuke issue. You could try looking into some [JavaScript solutions](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bobosola/index.htm) that help with IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "pngfix" should find a lot of different techniques for enabling alpha transparency in IE6.

One common one is a [HTC behaviour file](http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/pngbehavior/pngbehavior.html).

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with DotNetNuke, it's an IE6 thing.  IE6 doesn't do very well with certain transparent PNG.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  IE6 only supports a specific, and visually ugly, version of PNG transparency.  I believe its PNG-8.

You can use a [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to handle IE6 differently:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
background-image:crappy.gif
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some discussions regarding this on dotnetnuke.com forums, but I had the wrong date criteria in my search so the reason I didn't see any responses previously and thought I would ask here.

I think I found what I am looking for from a dotnetnuke perspective its a module that you install on your page which fixes this problem automatically.  But unfortunately you have to pay for it.  (I won't post the link since I don't want people thinking I was am asking just to advertise for them.)